# Trying to read a row of csv file modifying it

Tags: java

I have two csv file master and modified

master have three cell 
1.FileName
2 File MD5 value
3 #

modified
1 File Name
2 its md5 value

I have two check if modified.csv file name exists in master then swap the two md5 value of each file and write it to master.csv.master.csv contains around 6435 rows so it should only modify a particular row

this is what i have written and its nowt working.

```
String s1,s2;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
BufferedReader modified_reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(modified_file));
BufferedReader master_reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(master_file));
FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(master_file.getName());
while((s1=modified_reader.readLine())!=null)
{

String[] modified_lines=s1.split(",");
System.out.println(modified_lines[0]+"   "+modified_lines[1]);
while((s2=master_reader.readLine())!=null)
{
String[] master_lines=s2.split(",");
System.out.println(master_lines[0]+"   "+master_lines[1]+"  "+master_lines[2]);
if(modified_lines[0].equalsIgnoreCase(master_lines[0]))
{
master_lines[1]=modified_lines[1];
                              master_lines[2]=sdf.format(modified_file.lastModified());
fw.write(master_lines[0]);
fw.write(',');
fw.write(master_lines[1]);
fw.write(',');
fw.write(master_lines[2]+"DOne");
fw.flush();
//fw.close();

}


}


}
```

The problem here is its not modying the master.csv file with the swapped value and i am trying to get the file last modified time and change it with #

Comment: as far as i know you cant "modify" a file, you can only append a line at the end of the file, if you want to modify it, you need to create a new file...

Comment: Ok how to delete an exiting matching row and append the new at the end of file...will that work means a new entry(a new row)